# Find closed shapes in image

Tags: python, image, shapes

I need to find all closed shapes in an image and get coordinates of it. I need this in Python but a explanation on how to do this is also enough. Feel free to answer with Python code if you want though. I already searched a lot on Google and found these two things:

- [WPF: Finding all closed areas in an image (C# or even VB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269967/wpf-finding-all-closed-areas-in-an-image-c-or-even-vb)
- [determine if a point sits inside an arbitrary shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486499/determine-if-a-point-sits-inside-an-arbitrary-shape)

The answer in the first link paints all areas instead of giving me coordinates of closed areas. I don't understand the first answer in the second link and some comments say it doesn't work. The second answer in the second link doesn't work for images like this:

[image: some image]

I tried to make my own code too, but it took longer than a second to calculate and it has to be much faster (not really, really fast, but at least faster than 1/10 second).

How can I find these areas?

PS: There are some lines in the images that aren't part of a closed shape.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the content of the image? If not, how do you define a closed area precisely?

Comment: Is your image a natural image or consists of synthetic objects like the example you mentioned.

What do you mean by coordinates ? In case of the example image , you need the coordinates of the black region or white region inside ?

Comment: BartoszKP, The content is some black lines drawn with pygame (both curved and straight lines).  Koustav Ghosal, It can be everything drawn with some lines, by coordinates I mean a point in a closed area, the closed area is the white area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function `find_groups` that groups each pixel in the image into one of three categories: free, closed and border, along with a function `print_groups` to test it in a readable way.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from copy import deepcopy

def find_groups(inpixels):
    """
    Group the pixels in the image into three categories: free, closed, and
    border.
        free: A white pixel with a path to outside the image.
        closed: A white pixels with no path to outside the image.
        border: A black pixel.

    Params:
        pixels: A collection of columns of rows of pixels. 0 is black 1 is
                white.

    Return:
        PixelGroups with attributes free, closed and border.
        Each is a list of tuples (y, x).
    """

    # Pad the entire image with white pixels.
    width = len(inpixels[0]) + 2
    height = len(inpixels) + 2
    pixels = deepcopy(inpixels)
    for y in pixels:
        y.insert(0, 1)
        y.append(1)
    pixels.insert(0, [1 for x in range(width)])
    pixels.append([1 for x in range(width)])

    # The free pixels are found through a breadth first traversal.
    queue = [(0,0)]
    visited = [(0,0)]
    while queue:
        y, x = queue.pop(0)

        adjacent = ((y+1, x), (y-1, x), (y, x+1), (y, x-1))
        for n in adjacent:
            if (-1 < n[0] < height and -1 < n[1] < width and
                                        not n in visited and 
                                    pixels[n[0]][n[1]] == 1):
                queue.append(n)
                visited.append(n)

    # Remove the padding and make the categories.
    freecoords = [(y-1, x-1) for (y, x) in visited if
                 (0 < y < height-1 and 0 < x < width-1)]
    allcoords = [(y, x) for y in range(height-2) for x in range(width-2)]
    complement = [i for i in allcoords if not i in freecoords]
    bordercoords = [(y, x) for (y, x) in complement if inpixels[y][x] == 0]
    closedcoords = [(y, x) for (y, x) in complement if inpixels[y][x] == 1]

    PixelGroups = namedtuple('PixelGroups', ['free', 'closed', 'border'])
    return PixelGroups(freecoords, closedcoords, bordercoords)

def print_groups(ysize, xsize, pixelgroups):
    ys= []
    for y in range(ysize):
        xs = []
        for x in range(xsize):
            if (y, x) in pixelgroups.free:
                xs.append('.')
            elif (y, x) in pixelgroups.closed:
                xs.append('X')
            elif (y, x) in pixelgroups.border:
                xs.append('#')
        ys.append(xs)
    print('\n'.join([' '.join(k) for k in ys]))
```

Now to use it:

```
pixels = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
          [1, 0 ,1 ,1 ,0, 1],
          [1, 0, 1 ,0 ,1, 1],
          [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
pixelgroups = find_groups(pixels)
print_groups(7, 6, pixelgroups)
print("closed: " + str(pixelgroups.closed))
```

Outputs:

```
# . # # . .
. # X X # .
. # X X # .
. # X X # .
. # X # . .
. # # . . .
. . . . . .

closed: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2)]
```

You'll notice random dots and streaks are classified as borders. But you can always distinguish between real borders and streaks as follows.

```
# pseudo code
realborders = [i for i in pixelgroups.border if i has an adjacent closed pixel]
streaks = [otherwise]
```

Comment: There misses some code in your example, what's after "not n in visited and"?

Comment: And I think it doesn't work if a line that's not in a closed shape hits the image border.

Comment: @user2746752 Good point. I got everything working and updated the post. To get around the line hitting the border problem the function now pads the image with white pixels so it will just go around anything in its way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [mahotas](https://luispedro.org/software/mahotas/)

```py
import mahotas
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# loading nuclear image
f = mahotas.demos.load('nuclear')
 
# setting filter to the image
f = f[:, :, 0]
 
# setting gaussian filter
f = mahotas.gaussian_filter(f, 4)
 
# setting threshold value
f = (f> f.mean())
 
# creating a labelled image
labelled, n_nucleus = mahotas.label(f)
 
#plotting
axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,3))[1]
plt.sca(axs[0])
plt.imshow(f)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('orginal image')

plt.sca(axs[1])
plt.imshow(labelled)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('labelled_image')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]